# Limited pixel values in layer effects and styles (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-effects, layer-style

Some layer effects and styles in Photoshop have pixel settings. The problem appears when you want to scale your design. For example, in `Bevel and Emboss` you are able to set the `Size` and `Soften`. The former is limited to `250px` and the latter to `16px`.

To scale and preserve my design I need to set values greater than the Photoshop limits. Is it possible to do that? Any workaround?

Moving to Illustrator is not a solution, since some Photoshop effects that I'm using are not present in Illustrator.

Answer (score 3):

The only work around is creating the effects yourself.
It may seem daunting at first. But in reality most effects are just..

- Duplicating the current layer.
- Setting a clipping mask of the original to the duplicate.
- Setting a blur, color, stroke effect on the duplicate.

Different combinations of the last step will achieve different layer effects.

Answer (score 2):

With my massive 3500pt text in a bold (Impact) at the upper echelon of what Bevel and Emboss can do natively we get this:

[image]

Now if we need to go beyond that we move to Scale Effects which can be found by right clicking on the effect in your layer panel, or under Layer → Layer Style on the main menu system. **This only scales beyond the limit for the "Softness" however, if there is a softness, not the size value.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Scale Effects* option (see [@Ryan's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/71638/52050)), but that won't scale effects *past their maximum value* (it seems it will scale *soften* and possibly some other values past their maximum but not *size* values).

In that case—No. There is no way to apply effects bigger than their maximum *size*. Either:

1. Recreate the effect yourself.
2. Work at a smaller scale.
3. Create your bevel at a smaller scale, convert the layer to a smart object and enlarge the smart object. Your beveled layer will be at a lower resolution than the rest of your document however.