# How to set inner glow (vignette) effect size to value bigger than 250

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-effects, layer-style, vignette

So, I have .PSD document in lower resolution with a background layer that has vignette effect on it. But, when I copy layer style from that layer, the size of inner glow stays the same, ergo, smaller on the bigger canvas. Now, here lies the problem, slider only goes to 250 px. Is there any reason behind this limit? And, is there a way to bypass this problem?

Here's a screenshot of layer style panel for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully get your question. Let me try to rephrase it. At a working size you have found the right settings for your inner glow. When you scale up, it's not the right size, and you can't get to the right size due to the 250 units limit in inner glow?

Comment: That is exactly my problem.

Comment: there is only 256 levels of opacity so anything beyond that is a bit suspect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limited pixel values in layer effects and styles (Photoshop)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29164/limited-pixel-values-in-layer-effects-and-styles-photoshop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hacky, and destructive.

Create the internal shadow on its own layer, and set blend mode as required. When you need to upscale, rasterise this layer. Fortunately there's almost no detail inside a blurred shadow, so the scaling shouldn't be noticeably negative to the quality of the image. But will retain its relative size.

Answer (score 0):

I use this thechnique:

1. draw a shape (small)
2. apply your effect
3. convert to smart object
4. scale your shape

Hope this helps.